# Reverse numbers using java arrays

Tags: java

Hello I am new to java and am trying to do this assignment but I can't get the needed output which is the reverse order of the numbers. Can any one help me what I am missing? Thank you so much! **My Code's output looks like this:**

> How many floating point numbers do you want to type: 5 Type in 1.
>   number: 5,4 Type in 2. number: 6 Type in 3. number: 7,2 Type in 4.
>   number: -5 Type in 5. number: 2
>
> Given numbers in reverse order:
>
> **Assignment**

Create a program that asks the user how many floating point numbers he wants to give. After this the program asks the numbers, stores them in an array and prints the contents of the array in reverse order.

Program is written to a class called ReverseNumbers.
Example output

How many floating point numbers do you want to type: 5
Type in 1. number: 5,4
Type in 2. number: 6
Type in 3. number: 7,2
Type in 4. number: -5
Type in 5. number: 2

Given numbers in reverse order:
2.0
-5.0
7.2
6.0
5.4

**My code:**

```
    import java.util.Scanner;  
public class apples {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);  

        double[] numbers;  

        System.out.print("How many floating point numbers do you want to type: ");  
        int size = reader.nextInt();  
        numbers = new double[size];  

        for (int i=0; i < numbers.length; i++) {  
            System.out.print("Type in "+(i+1)+". number:");  
            numbers[i-1] = reader.nextDouble();  

        }  

        System.out.println();  
        System.out.println("Given numbers in reverse order:");  

        for (int i=numbers.length-1; i <= 0; i--) {  

              System.out.println( numbers[i]);  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: `numbers[i-1]` would throw an `IndexOutOfBounds` exception. Change it just to `numbers[i]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second `for` loop condition is wrong. It should be:

```
for (int i = numbers.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

because `i <= 0` won't be true if `numbers.length - 1` is greater than 0, therefore your `for` loop won't run its body.

**Also** in the first `for` loop, the index of `numbers` are wrong. It should be:

```
numbers[i] = reader.nextDouble();
```

This is because if `i = 0`, then `numbers[i - 1]` will be `numbers[-1]`, and that's an invalid index.

Comment: No problem. Feel free to accept this answer if it was useful and solved your problem: [How does accepting an answer work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

In the first loop you are using `i+1` and not `i++`, so the value of i is never incremented. So, your

`numbers[i-1]` becomes `numbers[-1]`, which should throw an error. I am astonished, now your program is even giving you an output !

Try this

```
for (int i=0; i < numbers.length; i++) {  
        System.out.print("Type in "+(i+1)+". number:");  
        //numbers[i-1] = reader.nextDouble();  
        numbers[i] = reader.nextDouble(); 
    }
```

and in second loop. You are checking from last to first so `i>=0` instead of `i<=0`

```
for (int i=numbers.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {  
          System.out.println( numbers[i]);  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] numbers;
System.out.print("How many integer point numbers do you want to type: ");
int size = reader.nextInt();
numbers = new int[size];

for (int i=0; i < size; i++) {
    //System.out.print("Type in "+(i+1)+". number:");
    numbers[i] = reader.nextInt();
}

System.out.println();
System.out.println("Given numbers in reverse order:");

for (int i=size-1; i >= 0; i--) {
      System.out.print( numbers[i]);
}
```